# Change font color only for .txt files on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Anyone knows how can I customize the font color only for text *(.txt)* files in Notepad ++?

I know I can enable global foreground color in *Style Manager* under Global override Style:

[image: Style Manager]

But this will override text color for all files extensions.
I need to change the color only for *.txt* files.

In Style Configurator under Language section I can't find the option for text files.

Is this possible?

Comment: Create a new user language

Comment: @Toto Good idea, I'll try. Thanks!